# roleId: role.id, TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')

Tags: discord.js

```
const { options, guildId, member } = interaction;
const role = options.getRole("role");
const description = options.getString("description");
const emoji = options.getString("emoji");

  const newRole = {
    roleId: role.id,
    roleDescription: description || "No Description",
    roleEmoji: emoji || "",
  }
```

I have add the option as .addRoleOption
While coding ran into a error

/Users/surendrasah/Desktop/MonDisTech/Commands/Roles/AddRole.js:42
roleId: role.id,
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
at Object.execute

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when (as in the error) your variable (`id`) is *null*.
This may mean that your `id` is not defined. Double-check the id or try another one